# Is there a list somewhere of printer-drivers for 13.04

Tags: 13.04, printing

Before I purchase a new printer I would like to figure out if there is a linux driver available.

Comment: I would select a print and do a Google search to make sure there is a Linux version. If not, search for another printer.

Comment: You could check here: http://www.openprinting.org/printers

Answer (score 2):

You could check the [OpenPrinting Printer Listings](http://www.openprinting.org/printers). (Link kindly suggested by [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555).)

Most Linux distributions use CUPS so practically any printer will work. OS X also uses CUPS. In fact, Apple hired the chief developer and purchased the source code. See [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS) and [CUPS Homepage](http://www.cups.org/) for more info on CUPS.

Comment: I would also check here: http://www.openprinting.org/printers

Comment: Use the link @chili555 provided. It seems a little easier to find things.

Answer (score 0):

For HP printer dedicated driver available for linux but generally most of the printers automatically detected by the ubuntu os.